# WSDL differents namespaces for element type

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, wsdl

I am creating web service so I have to modify the .WSDL to add them. When I am doing it, I have an error on this line :

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MonitoringResult" type="tms:State" />
```

> undefined simple or complex type 'tms:State' (org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.0.4:wsdl2java:generate-sources:generate-sources)

Here my WSDL's declaration :

```
<wsdl:definitions 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
    xmlns:tms="http://***.com/***/evpt/util" 
    xmlns:tns="http://***.com/***/evpt/services/v1_0_0" 
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
    targetNamespace="http://***.com/***/evpt/services/v1_0_0" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
```

This code is working well, the method readObject() is returning an ObjectSet which is define in tns:ObjectSet (the class ObjectSet.java is in http://***.com/***/evpt/services/v1_0_0/ObjectSet.java)

```
  <s:element name="ReadObjects">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="keySet" type="tns:ObjectKeySet" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
  <s:element name="ReadObjectsResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ReadObjectsResult" type="tns:ObjectSet" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
```

But I've created another web method which returns a State which the classe is define in http://***.com/***/evpt/util/State.java. And when I try this :

```
<s:element name="Monitoring">
    <s:complexType/>
</s:element>
<s:element name="MonitoringResponse">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MonitoringResult" type="tms:State" />
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

It returns me an error on State. So I've define a namespace named "tms" in the wsdl definition, but it still not working.

Could you help me guys? Thanks !

Edit :

```
package com.***.***.evpt.util;

public enum State {
    RUNNING,
    STOPPED;
}
```

Comment: Please add the schema definition of `State` to your question.

Comment: What you mean by schema definition of State ? I do not have anything about State in the WSDL.
State is define like that : public enum State {
 RUNNING,
 STOPPED;
}

Comment: A schema's use of `type="tms:State"` requires the presence of `<s:complexType name="State">` or `<s:simpleType name="State">` somewhere else in the schema (or in one of the included/imported schemas).  Sounds like it's an XML schema issue, not a Java issue.

Comment: I do not have <s:complexType name="ObjectSet"> in the schema and it's working, about the readObjects method.

Comment: It's hard to determine what's going on without the complete WSDL.  (Feel free to change all the URIs to use example.com.)  If you are combining classes generated from a WSDL with classes written by hand, expect unpredictable and/or confusing results.  Either generate all classes from the WSDL, or generate the WSDL from your classes.

Comment: You were right !
It finally worked. Actually I'm editing the WSDL by hand and generate the services SOAP file. There are some generate issues in the project... Anyways ! Thanks :)

(Do I have to writte an answer to validate the topic or you're going to change your comment as an answer?)